# How do you initialize a singleton with properties - Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, singleton

I am trying to create a singleton that gets initialized with properties..  I know you can initialize by default:

```
class ApiSharedHelper {
    var someValue:String    

    static let sharedInstance : ApiSharedHelper = {
        let instance = ApiSharedHelper()
        return instance
    }()


ApiSharedHelper.sharedInstance...
```

And I would just call that sharedInstance and it'll call the constructor.  How would I call that shared instance where I'm passing a value for that `someValue` string to initialize a value?

Comment: That's a bad idea, because you never know if the "singleton" has already been initialized earlier, with different arguments. – If you need helpers dependent on some parameters then don't use a singleton (or, as I prefer, "shared instance")

Comment: Every object has it's own property and behavior, If you want to change the property value then simply use its sharedInstance. and if you want to assign at the time of init then you can assign the value in `sharedInstance ` block.

Comment: @MartinR yeah, that's why I want to know how to initialize a singleton with values from the beginning and declare the properties w/ let so they don't get modified..

Answer (score 2):

```
class APIManager {

    class var shared :APIManager {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = APIManager()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    func login(username: String, password: String, success:@escaping (LoginModel?)->()) { ... }
```

You can call it by :

```
APIManager.shared.login(username: txtUsername.text ?? "", password: txtPassword.text ?? "") { (response) in
            print(response ?? "")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
class ApiSharedHelper {
    var someValue:String    
    static let sharedInstance = ApiSharedHelper()
    private init(){
    }
}

ApiSharedHelper.sharedInstance...
```

Comment: Without making the initializer private, you don't ensure that `sharedInstance` will be a singleton.

Comment: It doesn't get any value when initialing.

Comment: you can provide default value in private init